# Dual boot ubuntu 18.04, GPU issues

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

Currently I am having to log into fresh install of Ubuntu with 'nomodeset' otherwise it black screens or the monitor loses signal. I have tried to follow this: "https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux" as well as installing the AMD drivers from their website and both have the same effect.

I am using two monitors, one is hdmi (monitor) to display port (GPU) and the other HDMI. Both plugged into the GPU not the motherboard.

GPU: r9 390

CPU: i5-4690k

When I boot without 'nodemodeset' it picks up both monitors and at the correct resolution, but black screens after login. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

*Secondly in my graphics config when Ubuntu actually booted with my r9 390 it said the driver = radeon, but if I'm using ppa:oibaf should this not = amdgpu? How do I force it to use the amdgpu drivers?

----------------------------------------------------------**Final Edit**------------------------------------------------------------

It seems I have managed to fix my issue, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have fixed my issue, I believe the issue was that it would use either radeon's driver which was unstable (black screen) or fallback to llvmpipe drivers, in short I had to blacklist radeon and force amdgpu drivers.

I have managed to reboot 4 times without `nomodeset` with no issue occurring. I can now also customise my resolution/refresh rate, and both monitors are supported and functional. In the case of someone else finding this post through a search engine here are the steps I took that worked for me on my **r9 390**.

- Install this PPA for the latest drivers - "https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers"

then

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
```

- Add this to /etc/x11/xorg.conf or /etc/xorg.conf -

`Section "Device"`

```
      Identifier "AMDGPU"     
      Driver "amdgpu"     
      Option "AccelMethod" "glamor"    
      Option "DRI" "3"
```

`EndSection`

I did 1&2 following this - "https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux"

- Add this to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf -

`blacklist radeon`

then

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

- Add this to /etc/default/grub -

`GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x32`

`radeon.cik_support=0 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1 amdgpu.dpm=1`

then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Found step 4 from here -

"[How to set Display Resolution while having to use "NOMODESET" on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761149/how-to-set-display-resolution-while-having-to-use-nomodeset-on-boot?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)"

&

"https://community.amd.com/thread/220560"

This is what worked for me at the time of this post running **Ubuntu 18.04**. Black listing radeon may cause some issues if you do not have a driver installed, in my case black listing it caused Ubuntu to fall back to the llvmpipe drivers, so I had to add some lines to the grub file to use amdgpu as it was not automatically being used.

Comment: Hi. I followed this and after doing everything you have mentioned I am getting error saying ACPI Error

Answer (score 0):

well, this is the problem with AMD cards you dont have to again and again and nomodeset just edit the grub file add the nomodeset , save and "sudo update-grub".

This was also the problem with Nvidia cards back in ubuntu 16.04 but now it runs without nomodeset. On linux mint it adds nomodeset on installing drivers.

Comment: Yes I have done this, but the problem is I do not think it is using the drivers and 'nomodeset' locks my resolution to 1280x720 which makes the screen quite small.

Comment: Grub also has an option of screen resolution try changing that to your screen and then it should work fine.

Comment: hey i think this thing got your solution     https://askubuntu.com/questions/761149/how-to-set-display-resolution-while-having-to-use-nomodeset-on-boot?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I guess that should work, but I would have to use 1 monitor. My black screen does not seem to go away even if I wait. I will try to use some of the grub settings.

Comment: Great You are able to fix it.. i thought of blacklisting but that sometimes is just a bit too risky all of the GUI is gone and left with no choice XD

Answer (score 0):

I see you have the same GPU and CPU as I have. If you have any further problems, I would strongly advise you to add `radeon.dpm=0` in your GPU options which disables the dynamic power management of the GPU. This solved black screen crashes for me.