# Ubuntu hangs due to Xorg process

Tags: 20.04, xorg, freeze

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Once in a fortnight or so, the system hangs, and the system fan goes to full speed at the same time. After that, no keyboard or mouse input works, not even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to switch to a command line console. So there is no way for me to monitor if any background process is malfunctioning. The only choice I have is to use the power button to reboot.

Last time this event repeated, I managed to log in to the computer remotely using ssh (didn't expect it would work, but it did). And then I was able to use `htop` to see the processes.

[image: htop]

One of the Xorg processes seems to be occupying a lot of space. I don't know much about the X processes. Please help me understand this problem and find a solution if possible.

P.S. Please do not confuse with the Linux Mint logo on the screenshot, as that screenshot was  taken from a remote client running Mint.

Comment: Why is there a Linux Mint logo on the screen?  Linux Mint uses runtime *adjustments* so they can use Ubuntu packages (and not build everything themselves) which means it's a different system, and adds an extra software layer that can explain this issue... Are you using Ubuntu or Linux Mint?

Comment: @guiverc, this picture is from a remove connection, so could be a Mint client logged in on an Ubuntu 20 system ;) I do not see processes consuming lots of memory or CPU, though.

Comment: That's right. The screenshot is from the remote client. Yes @vanadium, the CPU usage is not a lot, but Xorg is using 1 core at 95%, which even though unusual, shouldn't cause Ubuntu to hang.

Comment: Next time this event repeats, I will get `htop` results again to confirm if `Xorg` is actually the culprit. Please advise if I should extract any other logs

Comment: History repeated itself, and I found that the same process is the peak consumer of CPU. But I don't know why that should breakdown the session.

Comment: Anyone trying to close this question because it's not Ubuntu, please retract your votes. Just because you use Mint to log in to an Ubuntu session does not make it off-topic. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @ArturMeinild for supporting the question. Didn't know that it was downvoted.

Comment: Tried reinstalling Xorg using `apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg`, but still facing the same problem

Comment: I observe sometimes the same problem, but I think it's caused by firefox (especially on youtube) after resuming from screen lock. Maybe this is some kind of cross problem with xorg? I searched [xorg issue board](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/issues/?scope=all&state=all) but couldn't find anything useful ...

Comment: @Mischa thanks for the comment. I do use firefox, but I hardly use YouTube. I wonder what is the problem

Comment: Finally, I gave up on Xorg and switched to wayland using this post https://askubuntu.com/a/1258280/719400. Should see how it goes. Could be useful for you @Mischa