# Grub Resolution carries over to Linux

Tags: boot, grub2, display-resolution, bios, nomodeset

So, I changed the resolution of grub by editing the `GRUB_GFXMODE` line in `/etc/default/grub`. I also added `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

Now the problem is, that whenever I boot into Ubuntu, the resolution of grub (800x600) remains. That's not the case when I boot into Windows with grub. I also changed `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX`, but that doesn't affect my problem in any way.

Eventually I figured out that without `nomodeset` this problem doesn't occur. Unfortunately I need that flag, as otherwise my PC will boot into a black screen sometimes, with the only way to exit is by killing my PC off.

Any suggestions what could be the problem? I have a **AMD RADEON VEGA 10** (Integrated Chip), if that's of any interest.

**Information**: 
OS is Ubuntu MATE 20.04 
The AMD Driver is the open source amdgpu. It came out of the box with Ubuntu 
The GFXMODE line looks as follows: `GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600` 
When that line is commented out the grub menu has a resolution of 1920x1080, thus making it very slow

Comment: Commenting out GRUB_GFXMODE won't slow down anything, it'll only change your GRUB screen resolution, and may fix your black screen problem. Also, your value of 800x600 doesn't sound like your monitor/display can handle that, as it doesn't appear to be any standard size. Leave GRUB_GFXMODE commented out, set GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX back to default, and do `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Grub is very slow and steady, inputs are processed very slowly at high resolutions. Commenting out can't fix my black screen problem, as I only began to modify grub in order to fix my black screen. While doing so I saw the resolution option and wanted to change it, so grub becomes fast reacting.
I ran videoinfo in the grub cli and 800x600 was on of the resolutions it throw back at me, so I think that works.
However I already came up with a fix and answered my own question. Thank you nonetheless!

Comment: If possible you should boot with UEFI, which will (among other things) cause grub to use your native monitor resolution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After even more research, some trial and error, and getting it to work finally, I can say, that **replacing** `nomodeset` with

```
modeset=0
```

solved my problem

It seems as `nomodeset` forces the display to stay at grub resolution, even after booting. I found that out [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761149/how-to-set-display-resolution-while-having-to-use-nomodeset-on-boot). `modeset=0` also prevents a black screen, but it doesn't come with the drawback of a permanent resolution.