# How to resolve the NOMODESET causing black screen problem for older Nvidia Cards in Kubuntu?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, display-resolution

I installed a fresh version of Kubuntu 18.04.5 in my old MSI CR400 with Intel Celeron 900, 4 GB RAM and NVidia GeForce 8200M Graphics. First of all the normal boot from a USB Image doesn't go through, it get stuck in a black screen for eternity. I googled what caused this problem and folks here said I should probably run it with `nomodeset` which can be set at USB boot using `f6`. So I set it and it started working. Now when I finished installing and reboot, it reboots normally, but at a fixed resolution of 648x480. My screen is a 1366x768 display and the Windows 8.1 I am Dual Booting runs smooth on it.
What's more is that during USB Live Boot with `nomodeset` enabled, it ran at a resolution of 1024x768. So next I disabled/removed `nomodeset` during the GRUB prompt by pressing `e` at boot time.
But then it didn't even move to the login screen, it just stays blank.

Next I opened up a Stack Exchange thread and it said to change display drivers to NVidia Proprietary Drivers, which I did, only to find my system crashing as I opened System Settings to check / change my display resolution. This is not working at all. The thread later mentioned that the drivers from before version 40 don't support the display method or something.

Today, I decided to take one more shot and then ran into these same problems, so this time I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761149/how-to-set-display-resolution-while-having-to-use-nomodeset-on-boot) thread. But alas nothing worked. Do I have to make do with the bad resolution coz of the unsupported drivers or is there any other solution. Please help me, I need to make this  work or else I am stuck using a really Intel N270 Powered Laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Your card is somewhat older (it is good to keep the the old hardware alive) but you will have to install an older nvidia driver before you could get rid of the "nomodeset".

Add the "nomodeset" to grub again, install the Nvidia 340.xxx driver - then you should be go and remove that flag again.
See [installing Nvidia 340 driver](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365644/906933) which has been asked recently.

Don't forget to `update-grub`after the changes you've made in `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: "install the Nvidia 340.xxx driver". Some instructions would be useful if this is an answer!

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Do we have any ideas why it runs fine during install and as soon as it is done installing it starts behaving weird? Also there is one more thing I noticed, I am running an i386 version, I'll change to a 64 bit version and try this fix